# Issue while passing values from data-frame into python Email sending function using boto3

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, boto3, amazon-ses

I want to send customized emails from python based on the subject and address stored in a dataframe.I am using `boto3` and `AWS SES` for sending email.

If the `to_address` is `''`then value is taken `B_Address`

```
Email.head(5)

subject                               to_address          cc_address                     B_Address
Regarding Service Request -1234       david@gmail.com      cate@yahoo.com                 taha@yahoo.com
Regarding Service Request -7834       simon@gmail.com      toby@yahoo.com                 joy@yahoo.com
Regarding Service Request -5678       charles@gmail.com    zoy@yahoo.com,jame@yahoo.com   sara@yahoo.com
Regarding Service Request -5678                            joy@gmail.com                  sara@yahoo.com
```

**My current code**

```
    import boto3
    from os.path import basename
    from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
    from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
    from email.mime.text import MIMEText
    from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
    from email.utils import formatdate, COMMASPACE

    def create_message(send_from, send_to, cc_to,subject, plain_text_body):
        sender_address = "sender@gmail.com"
        mail_content="This is a test message"
        for a, b, c, d in zip(email['Subject'],
                              email['to_address'],
                              df['cc_address'],
                              email['B_Address']):
            to = d if b == '' else b
            subject = a
            cc_to = c
            message = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
            message['From'] = send_from
            message['To'] = COMMASPACE.join(send_to)
            message['Cc'] = cc_to
            message['Subject'] = subject
            message.attach(MIMEText(plain_text_body, 'plain'))
            return message
    
    def send_message(message):
        client = boto3.client("ses",region_name='eu-west-1')
        response = client.send_raw_email(RawMessage = {'Data': message.as_string()})

    message = create_message(sender_address,[to],cc_to,subject,mail_content)
    send_message(message)
```

This is not passing values correctly whats wrong in code? How to fix this.

Comment: You need to pass in more arguments in your call to the `create_method` function.`cc_to,subject, plain_text_body` are all 3 missing.

Comment: @GustavRasmussen, It was typo, I actually had that in my code

Comment: @GustavRasmussen, Is my logic correct?

Comment: It looks good I think. But I propose the following simplification: `to = d if b == '' else b`  (Using Pythons ternary statement).

Comment: `to` should be `send_to`. Also, check `sender_address` and `sender_from` and choose one or the other.

Comment: @DavidErickson,name `send_to` is not defined. I am getting this error.When I change

Comment: @GustavRasmussen, its giving me error name `to`is not defined.

Comment: @GustavRasmussen,Also when I adjusted code according to `David` still its not working